# How to make Hive table always available for downstream

Tags: hive, hiveql, data-warehouse

I am creating a hive table by doing joins of multiple source tables. This join takes approx 3 hours time because of huge data volume. This hive table is designed truncate and load. This table is further consumed by the downstream.

We plan to refresh this hive table 4 times a day because of data in source tables keep getting updated. Since table load is truncate and load, there will be no data in this table for approx ~3 hr in each times because of join query takes this much of time. And due to this data will not be available for downstream.

Can someone suggest how we can continue to truncate and load the table and old data for downstream is still available during the fresh data loads in the table ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the option to ensure downstream gets the data during the ~3hr downtime is to create a read copy of the same table for the downstream systems. For example, create a `tableB` which is a `select * from tableA_with_joins`. This will ensure downstream receives the data from tableB even if a truncate load is happening on tableA.

One of the cons of this approach is that an additional time will be consumed in syncing the data from tableA to tableB. But will ensure your downstream receives the data even during the downtime.